# convert query to mysql stored procedure with 'where in clause'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to convert this mysql select query in to stored procedure

```
SELECT number FROM table WHERE number IN(1234567890,10234567890,20134567890,...,...)
```

Comment: create a stored proc ad place the query there ...

Answer (score 0):

Create stored procedure example:

```
   DELIMITER 
    CREATE PROCEDURE country_hos
    (IN con CHAR(20))
    BEGIN
      SELECT Name, HeadOfState FROM Country
      WHERE Continent = con;
    END 
    DELIMITER;
```

Call or run stored procedure

```
CALL country_hos('Europe');
```